# Invariant violation: could not find store in either the context or props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I created a store in Login.js and when an user logs in, a username sends to the store. Then in Profile.js I get this username and render it.

This is how the code looks like:

Profile.js

```
import { connect, Provider } from "react-redux";

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    user: state.user
  }
}
export class Profil extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View>
          <Header
            centerComponent={{ text: 'Profil', style: { color: '#FF0000', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' } }}
            outerContainerStyles={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }}
          />
          <Text>Willkommen { this.props.user } </Text>
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Profil)
```

Login.js

```
body: JSON.stringify({

  email: UserEmail,

  password: UserPassword,

  name: UserName

})

}).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {

      // If server response message same as Data Matched
     if(responseJson === 'Data Matched')
      {

          //Then open Profile activity and send user email to profile activity.
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Tabs");
          store.dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_USER',
            user: { Name: UserName }
          });

      }
....

var userReducer = function(state, action) {
 if (state === undefined) {
  state = [];
}
 if (action.type === 'ADD_USER') {
  state.push(action.user);
}
return state;
}

export var store = createStore(userReducer);
```

But every time when I run the app, I receive the same error: Invariant violation: could not find store in either the context or props

What's the problem here? And how can I fix it?

Comment: I just answered a similar question a few moments ago, you can follow the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51800816/6606831)

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists, because `<Provider store={store}>` should be wrapped in your initial application context. `connect()` is not possible, because at this point the store has not been initialized in your parent app context, and it's trying to map your state to props, when the state itself is being set in the current component. Make sure `<Provider>` is wrapped in a component that doesn't not require `connect()` like below:

```
export var store = createStore(userReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MyAppComponent />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

At this point, `connect()` will work in any of your child components, and will read from the store.

Comment: What does "rootEl" mean in this context?

Comment: @DrueTrue I've updated. `rootEl` is simply where your app is mounted in your DOM. When you initialize the store: You'll shortly after be rendering the app into the actual page. At this point is when you want to take the store that you just initialized, and pass it to `<Provider>` for initialization (Wrapped around your root app component).

Comment: Now I receive: "Can't find variable: ReactDOM". Should I import it from react-redux?

Comment: ReactDOM is the react package that you use to actually render your app into the browser.

Comment: But if I use React Native for a mobile app, how should I do it then?

Comment: @DrueTrue Just wrap `<Provider>` around your ROOT component.

Comment: @DrueTrue Did you figure it out?

Comment: I don't get what you mean with root component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177904/discussion-between-frankerz-and-druetrue).